# how to get nodes where there is id attribute in html document using php

Tags: php, html, dom

how to get reference of node where there is id attribute set from an entire HTML documents using php (domdocument)?

```
<div id='foo'>
lorem ipsum
</div>
<div id='bar'>
lorem ipsum
</div>
<div id="baf">
  <div id="alpha">
  lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

i want to get list of foo,bar,baf,alpha nodes. nodes can be arbitrarily existed.

Comment: And [what have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: This smells like you did not understand the separation of the DOM tree inside a client browser and PHP running on a server. Or do you want to parse an html structure you have fetched and buffered on the server?

Comment: @njk i have not tried anything yet. what i thought was recursively looping through the whole document, but that does not seems right. so looking for any alternative idea.

Comment: Where is that html "document" you want to process with PHP? How does PHP access that HTML?

Comment: @arkascha http://php.net/domdocument

Comment: @fallenAngel http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php perhaps?

Comment: @fallenAngel: And you really don't think that such information should be part of your question? How is anyone meant to answer without that you describe your setup?

Comment: @sara but it will get any particular id which we will give it as parameter. i am trying to get all of the nodes which have an `id`.

Comment: In that case, I think the phrasing of your question is misleading.

Comment: @arkascha i realized it later and edited OP.

Comment: @Sara i apologize for that. English is not my native language. Let me edit the OP and fix it.

Comment: @fallenAngel I submitted an edit for you. After reading the documentation you linked, I think you're going to have to loop over the entire tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [str_get_html](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

```
$html = '<div id="foo">
lorem ipsum
</div>
<div id="bar">
lorem ipsum
</div>
<div id="baf">
  <div id="alpha">
  lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>';

$html = str_get_html($html);
foreach ( $html->find("div") as $value ) {
    var_dump($value->id);
}
```

Output

```
string 'foo' (length=3)
string 'bar' (length=3)
string 'baf' (length=3)
string 'alpha' (length=5)
```